# Should I use html&css&jquery already coded template?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, templates, designer

I am an intermediate level web designer & web developer. I built 5 official websites for hotels and not only, until now(2 years experience). But I have an uncertainty.

Should I use an already coded template like [this](http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/) for building the next websites? I already did 1 website with that great template and it saved me a good amount of time. My fear is that without that template, I don't have excellent skill for coding components like navbar, footer, making a page element to stay on the page in the position I want, etc.

I'm almost always copying code snippets from the net, let's say not coding from scratch.

My thought is: hey, you're using a template, you're not a real web designer/developer. I was thinking to only use bootstrap + wordpress, but if I use that CANVAS template( it already has lots of bootstrap components coded, css and javascript for almost any situation ) it would save me even more time.

What do you say, guys, what should I do ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever it takes to achieve your objective in the fast manner and have quality output should be your way forward. I would not worry about purism of solutions used as the objective. When you need it, you will know it - as the time will come when you know this template is not enough, then you can go back to custom solutions. Ultimately no one can handle every aspect of the development, using open source, libraries and frameworks is nowadays a skill in itself. Reapplying easy modules will help you to focus on other crucial elements of your app ( move to mobile, speed, additional functionality etc.)

Comment: I see that most jobs that I look for require good HTML, CSS, JQUERY, Bootstrap and Wordpress skills. They don't mention any HTML5 Template. Can they forbid me to use that CANVAS template and stay at Bootstrap + Wordpress ?

Comment: It depends what job you want to do and your employer will likely tell you which framework should be used for a project, but hopefully you also get some coaching, time to learn etc. Overall mastering HTML, CSS, JavaScript and libraries like Jquery, frameworks like Bootstrap etc. - are key for serious development anyways, so you should definitely get good knowledge of these. Ultimately with Bootstrap is very much like working with plain HTML5, it handles jquery for you. Check their sites, good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your time! I appreciate !